# Display Background Color before Popup?

Tags: javascript, css, html

I would like to set a background color of green before the alert pops up.. how do I do this?

```
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
    <head><meta charset="utf-8" />
    <style>
html, body{
        background: #0f0;
}
    </style>
    </head>

    <title>Hi There!</title>
    <script LANGUAGE='JavaScript'>
            window.alert('Hello There!')
    </script>
```

I thought this would do the trick but the alert pops up on a white page

Comment: Take a look at your style tag... what are you styling, you have no selector. like  body { background: #0f0; }

Comment: @jsmartfo thank u! i did get it to work after adding html and body, but it doesnt work across all browsers.. is there any way to set a small delay before the javascript alert loads?

Comment: to delay the alert, use [`setTimeout`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window.setTimeout)

Comment: Working fine in all browser http://jsfiddle.net/jats_ptl/3c2qS/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use this:

```
<html>
    <head>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
        <meta charset="utf-8" />

        <title>Hi There!</title>

        <style>
            body{
                    background: #0f0;
            }
        </style>

        <script>
            function showMessage() {
                window.alert('Hello There!')
            }
        </script>
    </head>

    <body onload="showMessage();">
        ..
    </body>

</html>
```

Note the `onload` attribute in the `body` tag. The value of this attribute is JavaScript code that will be executed once the page is fully loaded (CSS, images, etc).

---

And if you really want a delay, change the `showMessage` function to something like this:

```
function showMessage() {
    var secondsDelay = 5; //5 seconds
    setTimeout(function() {
        window.alert('Hello There!');
    }, secondsDelay * 1000);
}
```